# Should I enable autosave when programming?

Tags: save, autosave

On one hand, I don't really want to press CTRL+S all the time when programming.
On the other hand, I fear some problems may arise when auto-saving.
Should I enable autosave, or just get used to CTRL-Sing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable it. Modern IDEs have a local history of your file. Using this local history, you can always return to a previous state if need be.

Giving an example for AndroidStudio/IntelliJ, you can right-click in any code file and select `Local History -> Show local history`. Other IDEs have the same functionality, read their documentation to find out how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the growing lack of ability to turn off auto-save in editors is terrible. It takes control away from the programmer.

Some languages auto-format on save or remove your unused imports on save (like Golang).

It makes you have to think about whether you code might run before it's bug-free.

Editors and IDEs should auto-save to *hidden backup files* in the background, not overwrite the actual file you're working on. If the editor crashes, the program can recover your work from the backup file.